# Simple bar chart showing proportions of categories for two variables

Tags: stata

In Stata I have two variables, one asking intent to vaccinate on a certain date with yes/no/not sure as response options, then a second variable asking the same question to the same participants several months later. I want to create a bar chart where there is a vertical bar for each variable and the proportion of people that selected each response shown stacked on one another.

Comment: Data example please. The Stata tag wiki explains how to post a data example as code. As you aren't even showing us the code you tried, a data example is the best way to make up.

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of a data example, or any attempt at code, here is a guess at some technique that you might find helpful.

With two variables `graph bar` (or `catplot` (SSC) or `tabplot` (*Stata Journal*)) will easily give a bar chart for the cross-classification of two categorical variables.

You seem to be asking for two marginal distributions side by side.

The easiest way to get that might be to produce two separate bar charts and then apply `graph combine`.

More work, but a better approach in many ways, is to restructure the data temporarily to allow application of `over()` and `by()`. This approach is explained at some length in [this paper](https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=gr0085). Here is sample code that anyone can run (note that it `clear`s any existing data).

```
/// toy dataset 
clear 
set obs 100 
set seed 2803
gen var1 = cond(_n <= 20, 1, cond(_n <= 30, 2, 3))
gen var2 = cond(_n <= 10, 1, cond(_n <= 20, 2, 3))

preserve 

/// use your own variable names
stack var1 var2, into(var) clear  
label def _stack 1 before 2 after 
label val _stack _stack 
label def var 1 no 2 "not sure" 3 yes 
label val var var 
set scheme s1color 
graph bar (percent), by(_stack, note("")) over(var) ytitle(percent) yla(, ang(h))
graph bar (percent), by(var, note("") row(1)) over(_stack) ytitle(percent) yla(, ang(h))

restore
```

I have regarded no, not sure, yes as a natural order.